# Generating Union Statements using Macros in SAS

Tags: sas-macro, proc-sql

I have a table named mylib.common_noun contains approximately 2000 records, though this can change bi-weekly. I am trying to generate the same number of union statements as the record count in mylib.common_noun

Structure of mylib.common_noun. Two Columns: Keywords and dname

```
Keywords DNAME
A        sas1
B        sas2
C        sas3
```

For example, say mylib.common_noun contains 3 records, then it should generate the union statements based on the variable dname and then run the following code

```
proc sql;
create table mylib.test_union as (select * from mylib.sas1
union
select * from chug.sas2
union
select * from chug.sas3);quit;
```

I ran the following code based on suggestions but it doesn't work.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
    file code;
    set mylib.common_noun;
    if _n_>1 then
        put 'create table mylib.test_union as';
    else put 'union '@;
    put 'select * from ' dname;

run;
proc sql;
    OPTIONS SOURCE2;

    %include code;
    ;
quit;
```

Error in Log:

```
  40            %include code;
    NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODE is file 
    41        +union select * from mylib.sas_out1
               _____
               180
    ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

    42        +create table mylib.test_union as
    43        +select * from mylib.sas_out2
    44        +create table mylib.test_union as
    45        +select * from mylib.sas_out3
```

Not sure how to make it work

Comment: You want to combine 2000 datasets in one step?  Why are you generating SQL code instead of data step code?

Comment: `+` is not part of the generated code. It is just part of the LOG, like the line numbers.  You need to show the log as it appears to see what is being flagged. At least from the PROC SQL statement onward. Prefix it with 4 spaces (or use ctrl-K to do automatically) so that it will display as a block of code and preserve the white space.

Comment: Note that you have commented out the `run;` statement, but that should not impact the execution as SAS will end the data step when it sees the proc step starting.

Comment: Because the test for whether to generate the CREATE keyword is backwards. `if _n_=1 then ...`

Comment: @Tom That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to generate code from data. While you could possibly generate the code using macro logic it might be easier to generate the code just using regular SAS statements instead.

You did not describe the structure of `chug.claimants` so let's just assume it has one variable named DATASET with values like "chug.sas_claimants2".  If not then just add some logic to create such a value from the variables it does have.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  file code ;
  set chug.claimants ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'create table chug.test as' ;
  else put 'union ' @ ;
  put 'select * from ' dataset ;
run;
proc sql ;
%include code ;
  ;
quit;
```

Not sure if PROC SQL code is the best code to generate. Why not just generate a SET statement?

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  file code ;
  set chug.claimants ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'set ';
  put dataset ;
run;
data chug.test ;
%include code ;
  ;
run;
```

You could also use `call execute()` to generate the code, but then there is no way to stop between the generation and execution phase and review the generated code. Or take advantage of the reporting writing features of the PUT statement.

Comment: You might need to generate the full statement into the temp file.  You can test in tow ways. First manually modify the generated file to include the full create statement and make sure it works.  Then you can modifying the code generating step to also generate beginning and end of the create statement into the text file. Using END= option on SET statement can help with knowing when to add the semi-colon to end the statement. The \_N_=1 check  can be used to generate the create statement and then use ELSE statement to generate the UNION keyword.

Comment: The execution of the code generation was not the problem. The problem was that you could not use %INCLUDE in the middle of a statement. So the start of the statement needs to be in the file that is being generated so that when it can be included by using %INCLUDE statement and the result is valid SAS code that can run.  I updated the code generation so that generated code starts with the beginning of the statement. I left out the ending semi-colon so keep the extra semi-colon in the code that includes the file.

Comment: Since you are generating code it is the SAS log that will show what code you actually (generated and) ran. You can use the SOURCE2 option or the /SOURCE2 switch on the %INCLUDE statement to have the log show the actual code included from the file.  That should help you debug the issue as the error message should be flagging the point in the code that is confusing. Perhaps there are missing spaces or extra spaces. Or missing values of your dname variable.

Comment: Looks like the name of the variable is not what you think it is. Perhaps DNAME is the LABEL on the variable instead of the variable name.

Comment: Then DNAME is numeric and has some missing values (or it is character and has some values of '.') to produce the periods in the generated code. Or perhaps you have a missing semi-colon in one of the PUT statements. Either way you should see notes in the log about uninitialized variables.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you ran and the log for both steps, it is impossible to see what log message look like in comments.  Limit the input list dataset to two or three observations to keep the log short.  (Unless the error is caused by too many unions).